# Harmon.ie very slow when retrieving a list of 23.000 items from SharePoint

Tags: harmon.ie

Recently one of my co-workers started having trouble with the Harmon.ie outlook add-in which freeze / goes unresponsive after retrieving a list of items from a sharepoint site with 23.000 items inside.

Anyone else had the same problems regarding the performance of Harmon.ie with larger SharePoint folders?

Best Regards

Rasmus

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has limits/issues with requests for more than 5,000 items at a time. I don't Harmon.ie... can it "page" data requests and read 5000 or fewer items at a time?

Which version of SharePoint are you using? 2007,2010,2013,2016,2019 or SharePoint Online?

The "List view threshold" can be changed from 5,000 to a larger number with the on-prem versions.

You can use REST web service calls with a CAML query to page requests in batches of 5000. (And then merge them in Harmon.ie if that is supported.)

The 5,000 limit is listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/install/software-boundaries-and-limits-0?redirectedfrom=MSDN#ListLibrary

More info:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-large-lists-and-libraries-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?redirectsourcepath=%252fen-gb%252farticle%252fmanage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784&omkt=en-us&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us